# Showing a subset of $\mathbb{P}(U)\times Gr_d(U)$ is a closed subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying algebraic geometry and I am stuck at the following problem.
Let $U$ be a finite dimensional $k$-vector space with $char(k)=0$. Let $Gr_d(U)$ be the Grassmanian of $U$ consisting of all $d$-dimensional subspaces $W<U$.
I need to show that $\{(p,W):p\in \mathbb{P}(W)\}\subset \mathbb{P}(U)\times Gr_d(U)$ is a closed subvariety but I have no clue where to start. So far I have shown that it is a quasi-projective variety of $\mathbb{P}(\wedge^d U)$ and guess that the idea to solve this problem is to say that $p\in W$ can be rewritten as the vanishing of the minors of some matrix made up from linear equations of $W$.
Thank you for any help !

Comment: [No-clue questions are frowned upon here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), even in the algebraic geometry tag. Please add some context - for instance, what do you know about the Grassmanian? Have you tried hands-on descriptions of any small examples?

Comment: That's better! Your idea about minors of a matrix is good. Can you figure out a way to write the condition "$p\in W$" in a linear-algebraic way that lets you talk about minors of a matrix? You may also get some idea of the general solution from doing a specific example like $Gr_1(k^4)$ and $Gr_2(k^4)$.